# How can I set the height of a UIRefreshControl?

Tags: ios, swift, refresh, pull, uirefreshcontrol

I have a refesh control simple like:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

I want the refreshControl to be bigger. I tried setting a `refreshControl.frame = CGRect(0, 0, 200, 200)` (Not exactly that one, but with that syntaxis) and it didn't work.

What else can I try?

Thank you

Comment: The pull distance seems to be very close to 50% of the tableView height.

FYI: You can't modify the pull distance of UIRefreshControl. For that you can search for custom refresh control

Comment: The issue is not about the pull distance, but the distance of the refresh view itself. The one that contains the spinner.

Comment: You can go on appcoda for custom refresh control where you can set pull distance, your custom spinner or image